# VS Code devcontainer uses old version of repository when cloning

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'd like to use "Clone Repository in Container Volume" in VS Code. But unfortunately the git repository contained `Dockerfile` with a command that failed, causing the container build to fail. This was fixed since then, but the command "Clone Repository in Container Volume" keeps using the old `Dockerfile` from the broken commit.

I already removed caches on the Docker host with `docker system prune --all`. Is there something else that needs to be reset?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that removing containers and images was not enough. VS Code was reusing the volume in which the old git repository was already present.

I solved the problem by removing volumes used by VS Code

```bash
docker volume list # to find volumes used by vscode
docker volume rm <ID>
```